# Float: Breakpoint when increasing by 1 does nothing

Tags: javascript, floating-point, numbers

Float is an approximation of a number.

`12345678901234567890 === 12345678901234567891` is `true`

while

`1234567890 === 1234567891` is `false`

What is the breakpoint where `num === num+1`?

I made this code to find it out but it just takes too long...

```
for(var i = 0;;){
    var old = i;
    if(++i === old) break;
}
console.log(i);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The breaking point is 2<sup>53</sup>.

```
console.log(9007199254740992 === 9007199254740993);
# true
console.log(9007199254740991 === 9007199254740992);
# false
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's also the same for the negative. How did you manage to find it out btw?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the numbers in the console. You will see the first example truncates after the 17th digit.

[image]

[Here's documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp) of the JavaScript floating point.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and it gives a rather misleading impression of how floating-point rounding works.

Answer (score 0):

found the breaking point through trial and error: 9007199254740991, 9007199254740992

```
var n = 1;
while (true) {
    n *= 2;
    if (n === n+1) {
        break;
    }
}

var a = Math.round(n/2);
var b = n;
while (a < b-1) {
    var m = Math.round((a + b) / 2);
    if (m === m+1) {
        b = m;
    } else {
        a = m;
    }
}
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gEdRh/